# Python object inside other objects are not isolated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was expecting the object items inside other python objects are isolated.
However, the following code shows my expected result is wrong. It seems python uses a central `item_list` for all `Group` items. How can I fix this?

```
class Item:
    name = ''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Group:
    item_list = []

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item_list.append(item)

g2 = Group(Item('bb1'))
g2.item_list.append(Item('bb2'))

group_list = []
group_list.append(Group(Item('aaa')))
group_list.append(g2)
group_list.append(Group(Item('ccc')))

print('len = ', len(group_list[-1].item_list))
print('bb2 = ', group_list[1].item_list[1].name)
```

Result

```
len =  4
bb2 =  bb1
```

Version

```
python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

Comment: Your `item_list` as well as `name` are class variables (think `static` in C++). Put them inside the constructor such as `self.item_list = []` to make them instance variables.

Comment: `class Group: \n self.item_list = []` gives me `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

Comment: Inside the constructor (i.e. inside `def __init__`. Don't define anything at the class level.

Comment: for future reference: you can use `id()` to check which objects are the same in memory. With `[id(group.item_list) for group in group_list]` you will see that all the lists are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all we should make a difference between class attributes and instance attributes. A class attribute (like `item_list`) *belongs* to the class itself (in this case "Group"), so it will be accessible by calling `Group.item_list`. On the other hand, you can define a `item_list` for every instance of Group by defining `self.item_list = []` inside the Group class constructor (`__init__`).
The `Group.item_list` array will be unique for the whole class, and thus will be suitable to store things that you want to share across instances (such as `g2`). 
The `self.item_list` array (that will be different for each instance of Group) will hold values exclusively for the instance itself, so each *Group* will have its own *item_list*. 
I think you are aiming for the second approach (instance variables) so you should move the definition of *item_list = []* inside the class constructor.
The result should look like this:

```py
class Item:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


class Group:

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item_list = []
        self.item_list.append(item)

item1 = Item("itemName")
group1 = Group(item1)

# This should print an array containing the *item1* instance
print(group1.item_list)
print(group1.item_list[0] == item1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables that are declared outside of the `__init__` method (in this case `item_list`) are shared between all instances of a class (called class variables), which is why your expected result is wrong.

On the other hand, variables inside the `__init__` only belong to the given instance of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Your using class variables, which are similar C++ `static` variables inside classes (i.e. that variable is shared by ALL class instances). You need to put it inside the `__init__` (constructor) to make it so each class creates its own version:

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Group:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item_list = []
        self.item_list.append(item)

    # Though typically you would also have a function like this:
    def add_item(self, item):
        self.item_list.append(item)

g2 = Group(Item('bb1'))
g2.item_list.append(Item('bb2'))

group_list = []
group_list.append(Group(Item('aaa')))
group_list.append(g2)
group_list.append(Group(Item('ccc')))

print('len = ', len(group_list[-1].item_list))
print('bb2 = ', group_list[1].item_list[1].name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instance vs class attributes is covered in other answers. I want to add that you can avoid having shared instance variables by using an immutable type (e.g. tuple) instead of a mutable type (e.g. list) for class attributes. Like that they won't be shared among instances while still allowing you to define class attributes.

```py
class Item:
    name = ''
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Group:

    item_list = tuple()

    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item_list += (item,)
```